# Would this question about image analysis of a macromolecule be on topic here?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

[This question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/60390/amplitudes-and-phases-of-transform-of-an-image) about image analysis of a macromolecule was recently posted to Photography SE. It's been rapidly closed because, as far as the denizens of Photography can tell, it's got little if anything to do with photography per se. Would it be appropriate for this site, and if not, are there any Stack Exchange sites it would be appropriate for?

Comment: This seems on-topic to me. From a chemistry perspective it's lacking in some details (e.g., what kind of transform). But I suspect it would get comments and answers here.

Comment: This sounds interesting and on-topic to me. On the other hand, Biology.SE apparently has a microscopy tag with about 50 questions, some of which even seem to cover post-processing of data (machine learning).

Comment: @GeoffHutchison ...and it will get closed here. :) But not as off-topic, at least.

Comment: This sounds like a useful field to expand our scope into. I'm not sure how well our community can support that, but that's okay I guess.

Comment: @MARamezani Why do you say it will be closed? There seems little point migrating a question just to have it closed.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Don't worry! (See that :) sign? I don't think the question is off topic here, but I can't assure you that in case it's unclear or homework, it won't get closed. I'm no expert in spectroscopy, but Geoff says it lacks details)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [question has now been migrated](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/26650/amplitudes-and-phases-of-transform-of-an-image). Thanks all for the guidance.